# Retrieve Class to which a Named Individual belongs to in OWL API 4.0

Tags: java, eclipse, owl-api

Consider a Named Individual "Cow". Its Class is also "Cow" and In turn Cow is subclass of Mammal and Mammal is subclass of livingbeing and so on. if i have access to the OWLNamedIndividual as follows:-

```
for (OWLNamedIndividual i : localUni.getIndividualsInSignature())
    {
      Code that should give me ...
      i = Cow (NamedIndividual)
      Class = Cow
      One Level up class = Mammal
    }
```

i tried the following but to no avail

```
System.out.println(i.getEntityType().getName()  );  
System.out.println(i.getEntityType().toString()  );  
System.out.println(i.getTypes(myontology) ); // this would give me error   NoSuchMethodError
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getEntityType()` only returns OWLCLASS/OWLOBJECTPROPERTY/OWLNAMEDIDIVIDUAL, i.e., OWLAPI specific values about what an entity is, not about its role in an ontology or position in a hierarchy.

Also, it is possible to pun (i.e., an `OWLNamedIndividual` and an `OWLClass` can have the same IRI), but the two entities are distinct, so from one you cannot go to the other directly.

`OWLNamedIndividual.getTypes(OWLOntology)` has been removed in version 4.
It is possible to achieve the same result with

`EntitySearcher.getTypes(OWLIndividual, OWLOntology)`

Note that the results will only be asserted types for the individual - in order to get inferred results, you need to use an `OWLReasoner`.

Reasoners are still built the same way as for OWLAPI 3: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/DL-Queries-with-a-real-reasoner

However there are no releases of reasoners using OWLAPI 4, as far as I know. There are a few experimental branches:
The version4 branch of JFact is in SNAPSHOT state: https://github.com/owlcs/jfact
A HermiT fork working with OWLAPI 4 is available here: https://github.com/ignazio1977/hermit-reasoner
Both will need local build to be used.

Comment: Do you recommend owl api 4.0 or should i stick with 3.x. Problem is, that the features i need are a mix of two APIs. eg. i.getType, i.hasDataPropertyValue (where i = OWLNamedIndl) are not avail in 4.0

Comment: and whats the difference between owlapi-distribution4.0.0.jar and owlapi-osgidistribution4.0.0.jar

Comment: The methods that you mention are now static methods on EntitySearcher.

Comment: the osgidistribution jar includes all dependencies, i.e., Guava, Guice, and the Sesame libraries. It is necessary to embed them to run in Protege 5, as those libraries are not packaged already as OSGi bundles. From regular code, you can use either one, it depends on how you manage your dependencies.

Comment: Version 3 will not get new features but will still get bug fixes, at least for a while. So which one you should use depends mostly on what you need right now. Long term, it's better to move to 4.

Comment: EntitySearcher.getTypes(indl,myontology) gave me the type of named indvidual as Cow. Now i want to go one step up. i have used reasoner.getSuperClasses(cow, false).getFlattened() but it would give me like Cow > Animal > Mammal > Living Being. i.e all superclasses. while i just want to know that Cow is Animal. how to do that? obliged.

Comment: reasoner.getSuperClasses(cow, true) will only give you the direct superclasses - in this case, I suppose Mammal (Animal should be a superclass of Mammal). The booleans in the interface are confusing, we know. There's a plan to improve it.